# Magento 1.9 Shopping cart becoming empty after login from cart page

Tags: checkout

I am facing a cart empty problem with my Magento 1.9 When I am visiting a website as a guest user and login in checkout flow then my shopping cart becomes empty in some cases.

I am looking forward to your solutions.

Comment: I have found a bug due to which this problem is coming with Magento 1.9. When user cookie timeout expires and customer automatic log out from the browser. When the same customer visited the same website again then he will see the same products which he has added as the login customer. In this case, the customer tries to log in then he will see that his cart becomes empty. For resolving this problem I have increased the cookie timeout from this solution I can reduce the frequency of the problem but the problem still exists. If you have any solution for this problem please help me.

Comment: Want to add this to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check value under `System > Configuration > Web > Session and Cookie Management` and also echo `phpinfo` to check value of `session.gc_maxlifetime`. By default it expires after 24 mins.